# How to do I access Jupyter Notebook from Terminal of Mac [ After updating the Mac OS from High Sierra to Catalina ]

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

I installed the new version of Catalina from the Apple store and replaced it with my older version of High Sierra.

Now my Macbook Air is running the Catalina version.

I opened the Macbook Terminal and typed jupyter notebook but it is giving me the error that

-bash: jupyter: command not found

How can I fix this error and again access jupyter notebook directly again from the Terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your old python packages didn't survive the update.  According to [the Jupyter website](https://jupyter.org/install), the easiest way to install Jupyter is with the `pip` command. Since the Python team is recommending everyone switch to Python3, the instructions would be:

```
python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

If that doesn't work, you probably also [need to install pip.](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py)

Comment: Glad to hear it - there's a way to check "This answered my question" which will help other folks who find this page.

Comment: Hello Mr. Dylan, It worked the 1st time but now when I am trying to open Jupyter notebook from my terminal it is giving me the error that zsh: command not found: jupyter.  I tried your second approach of installing the pip also but it is giving me  ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-19.3.1.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: It sounds like your pip/python PATH are not on your path. I think it's at `/usr/local/bin` - to add that to your path, type this at a Terminal window:
```
echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
```
then close that Terminal, and open a new one and try again.

If that doesn't work, type `mdfind -name jupyter` and add the directory that executable is in to your PATH in a similar way.